# NSwindow disappear

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow

I want to add a NSWindow the simple code is :

```
NSWindow* myWindow;
myWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100,100,300,300)
                                       styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
                                         backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                           defer:NO];
[myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

And the window appears for a second then disappears.
What's wrong?

- Xcode 4.5.2
- MacBookPro i5 10.8.2

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are not retaining the window.

Define `NSWindow* myWindow;` in .h as a property.

---

In .h

```
@property (strong)NSWindow* myWindow;
```

In .m

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

   if (self.myWindow==nil){
      self.myWindow= [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100,100,300,300)
                                               styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
                                                 backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                   defer:NO];
   }

   [self.myWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

}
```

EDIT:

If you want multiple windows to open from same button. Create an array

In .h

```
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *myWindowArray;
```

In .m

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {
    self.myWindow= [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(100,100,300,300)
                                                   styleMask:NSTitledWindowMask
                                                     backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered
                                                       defer:NO];


    [self.myWindowArray addObject:self.myWindow];

    for (NSWindow *win in self.myWindowArray) {
        [win makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];

    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Find the [application here](http://www.keepandshare.com/doc/view.php?id=5380700&da=y).

Comment: Make that "`self.myWindow`" and the answer will be much better.  Also, you probably need to do a check to see if there's already a window assigned to "`self.myWindow`" before creating a new one.

Comment: If I want always a new window when I click on the Button ?

Comment: You don't need to declare an instance variable if you're making a property, since the synthesis of the property will include an instance variable, and if you really want an ivar for some reason, there's no reason to declare it in .h—it's a private implementation detail of the class, so it belongs in that class's .m file.

Comment: @PeterHosey: oops...sorry to that ivar... I am from c/c++ backgroung and still say all instance of a class ans ivar. However in the code there is no ivar only property is there... :p